# SWF under block - firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flash

Hy, I have this code:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">
                <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="450" height="150" bgcolor=#d2d2d2  id="movie_name" align="middle"> 
                    <param name='flashvars' value='clickTag=http://stackoverflow.com/MyTarget&clickTarget=_blank' />
                    <PARAM name="quality" value="high">
                    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
                    <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always' />
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="file.swf" width="450" height="150" bgcolor=#d2d2d2 >
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> 
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/> </a> <!--[if !IE]>--> </object> <!--<![endif]--> </object>
            <i style="display:block; height: 150px; width: 450px;  position: relative; z-index: 9; margin-top: -150px;"></i>
            </a>
```

This code works in Google Chrome but not in Firefox. In Google Chrome when I click on SWF file that redirects me on stackoverflow. in Firefox I can not click any swf. Someone knows what can I do?

Comment: you have `<a>` inside `<a>` i wonder how even it works in chrome

Comment: I removed the line: <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> 
<imgsrc="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/> </a>, but it still does not work

Comment: then check for `<object>` open and closing tag, you have mistake here too closing `<object>` inside another `<object>`

Comment: thank you very much, I removed one <object> and now works

Comment: you are most welcome